# How To Sort Empty key & value in lower order if its null in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

What I need

- i Need when [comment]='' Field  is Null Then it Should  be sort & it would result in lower order.
- Array Structure

  ```
  [0] => Array
  (
      [type] => CACDA
      [metadata] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [amount] => 320
                      [comment] => 
                  )

          )

  )

   [1] => Array
  (
      [type] => CVMA
      [metadata] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [amount] => 320
                      [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                  )

          )

  )
  ```

source code

```
              unset($data[0]);
            //store types and the arrays the belong to    
                foreach($data as $k=>$v){
                $type[$v['type']][]=$k;
                }

                //loop types, creating result array
                foreach($type as $k=>$v){
                $tmp=array(
                'type'=>$k,
                'metadata'=>array()
                );
                //loop all the arrays of this type
                foreach($v as $w){
                //store in TMP
                $t=array(
                'amount' => $data[$w]['amount'],
                'comment' => $data[$w]['comment']
                );

               $t array structure

                                                                                 Array
                                    (
                                    [amount] => 320
                                    [comment] => 
                                    )
                                    Array
                                    (
                                    [amount] => 320
                                    [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                                    )
                                    Onsite After February 20Array
                                    (
                                    [amount] => 320
                                    [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                                    )
                                    Onsite After February 20Array
                                    (
                                    [amount] => 370
                                    [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                                    )
                                    Onsite After February 20Array
                                    (
                                    [amount] => 170
                                    [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                                    )
                //sort TMP on EMPTY value
                //usort($t,function ($a, $b) {
                //if($a == '' && $b != '') return 1;
                //if($b == '' && $a != '') return -1;
                //if($b == 0){return 1;}
                //return 0; 
                //});
                arsort($t['comment']);
                //store 
                $tmp['metadata'][]=$t;
                }
                $result[]=$tmp;
                }
```

output of array  after sorting Should come Like ex

```
      [1] => Array
    (
        [type] => CVMA
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 320
                        [comment] => Onsite After February 20
                    )

            )

    )
   [0] => Array
    (
        [type] => CACDA
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 320
                        [comment] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

- problem i having i have also tried with usort .
- i have tried with  arsort function but nothing is working for sorting .
- please suggest where i have done wrong .
- which sorting function i should use  for key & value in php.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [**`uasort`**](https://www.php.net/uasort).

```
uasort($array, function($a) {
     return ( is_null($a['metadata'][0]['comment']) OR $a['metadata'][0]['comment'] == "") ? 1 : -1;
});
```

https://eval.in/207091

Comment: How have you implemented it? What is your result?

Comment: i have debug the code error was in my code i used you r concept now its working fine

Answer (score 4):

`uasort()` or `usort()` are the ideal php functions for this purpose. Here's how to use them.

```
<pre>
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
  $ac = $a['metadata']['comment'];
  $bc = $b['metadata']['comment'];
  if ($ac and $bc) return 0; // no sort if not empty
  return ($ac > $bc) ? -1 : 1; // else sort
}

// Array to be sorted
$array[] = ['type'=>'CVMA',  'metadata'=>['amount'=>320, 'comment'=>'Onsite After February 20']];
$array[] = ['type'=>'CACDA', 'metadata'=>['amount'=>320, 'comment'=>'']];
$array[] = ['type'=>'CACDA', 'metadata'=>['amount'=>320, 'comment'=>'B']];
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

https://eval.in/207108

Comment: Awesome, it gives OPs desired result :) +1!

Comment: no its not working at all o/p Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => CACDA [metadata] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 320 [comment] => ) ) ) ) 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: @user2818060 503 seems an error produced by your server. The code works at https://eval.in/207108 though